# Python: How to correct misspelled names

Tags: python, spell-checking

I have a list with city names, which some of them are misspelled:

```
['bercelona', 'emstrdam', 'Praga']
```

And a list with all possible city names well spelled:

```
['New York', 'Amsterdam', 'Barcelona', 'Berlin', 'Prague']
```

I'm looking for an algorithm able to find the closest match between the names of the first and second list, and returns the first list with its well spelled names. So it should return the following list:

```
['Barcelona', 'Amsterdam', 'Prague']
```

Comment: ill use some language toolkit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use built-in Ratcliff and Obershelp algorithm:

```
def is_similar(first, second, ratio):
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, first, second).ratio() > ratio


first = ['bercelona', 'emstrdam', 'Praga']
second = ['New York', 'Amsterdam', 'Barcelona', 'Berlin', 'Prague']

result = [s for f in first for s in second if is_similar(f,s, 0.7)]
print result
['Barcelona', 'Amsterdam', 'Prague']
```

Where 0.7 is coefficient of similarity. It may do some tests for your case and set this value. It shows how similar are both of strings(1 - it's the same string, 0 - very different strings)

Comment: According to difflib's documentation, it is not the Levenshtein distance algorithm, but it serves a similar purpose, and I upvote the use of a standard library function.

Comment: @Gribouillis, you're right! it uses Ratcliff and Obershelp algorithm. I forgot about it.

Comment: @ebeneditos you may follow the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio

Comment: Thank you @pivanchy! It is a quite different approach but it's helpful. Please edit your first sentence in order to clarify it uses Ratcliff/Obershelp algorithm, not Levensthen's and if there are no better answers in one day I will accept it.

Comment: @ebeneditos, fixed! This approach needs some investigation for choosing optimal ratio rate, but it works fine as for own purposes as on production

Comment: could someone explain how the smiliarity is measuret with an example?

Answer (score 6):

This could be a good use case of a great package called [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy).

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import numpy as np

bad = ['bercelona', 'emstrdam', 'Praga']

good = ['New York', 'Amsterdam', 'Barcelona', 'Berlin', 'Prague']

# you can even set custom threshold and only return matches if above certain
# matching threshold
def correctspell(word, spellcorrect, thresh = 70):
    mtchs = map(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x, word) if fuzz.ratio(x, word) > thresh else None, spellcorrect)
    max = np.max(mtchs)
    if max is not None:
        return spellcorrect[mtchs.index(max)]
    else:
        return None

# get correct spelling
map(lambda x: correctspell(x, good, thresh = 70), bad) # ['Barcelona', 'Amsterdam', 'Prague']
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you should use Levenshtein distances between strings, I found a link with the following [Levenshtein Distance Algorithm for Python](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python):

```
# Define Levenshtein distance function (from the mentioned link)
def levenshtein(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) < len(s2):
        return levenshtein(s2, s1)

    if len(s2) == 0:
        return len(s1)

    previous_row = range(len(s2) + 1)
    for i, c1 in enumerate(s1):
        current_row = [i + 1]
        for j, c2 in enumerate(s2):
            insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + 1 
            deletions = current_row[j] + 1  
            substitutions = previous_row[j] + (c1 != c2)
            current_row.append(min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
        previous_row = current_row

    return previous_row[-1]
```

Once you got this, you should make a function able to find the closest match between a given string and the list with the well spelled names.

```
names_list = ['bercelona', 'emstrdam', 'Praga']
good_names = ['New York', 'Amsterdam', 'Barcelona', 'Berlin', 'Prague']

# Define a function that returns the best match
def get_closest_match(name, real_names):
    levdist = [levenshtein(name, real_name) for real_name in real_names]
    for i in range(len(levdist)):
        if levdist[i] == min(levdist):
            return real_names[i]

# Loops the first list
final_list = [ get_closest_match(name, good_names) for name in names_list ]
```

Finally you just have to loop the first list with this function. The outcome is the following:

```
>>> print final_list
['Barcelona', 'Amsterdam', 'Prague']
```

Comment: You asked and answered your own question within a minute of each other?

Comment: When you ask a question, at the end there is a 'Answer your own question' option. StackOverflow encourages doing that so other people benefits from it. This was a problem I faced a couple days ago and I couldn't find a solution here. Thus I made this algorithm and I'm posting it now so that others can see it and propose better answers as well :)

Comment: @Dan-Dev: Self-answering is explicitly *encouraged*, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: @martijn-pieters it seems a bit extreme to ask and answer a question within one minute. He said he faced this problem a couple of days ago. However he did not ask it then. Also says that there was nothing on SO about the problem while the search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=levenshtein shows over 3,000 hits. Does SO encourage posting questions the poster knows the answer to?

Comment: Did you read the link? Yes, that is encouraged. The point being that this site collects knowledge, and self-answering is a way of sharing that knowledge. If you have further questions about this feel free to ask on [Meta]! :-)